# PHP - Trying to get json_encode to add commas and brackets

Tags: php, json

I have an application that displays a list of websites and some information about them based on a JSON file. I'm trying to make it so that users of the application can add new site listings by themselves with a web form.

The problem I'm having is that when I use JSON_ENCODE, there are no opening or closing brackets on the JSON file it appends - and there are no commas separating each object either.

My application will not read the JSON file without these characters added. I have done a lot of research and have been banging my head against the wall for a few days on this one. I am very new to PHP so please forgive me if this has been answered already, but I have searched and had no luck.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['age']) && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['image']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['snippet0']) && isset($_POST['snippet1']) 
  && isset($_POST['snippet3']) && isset($_POST['snippet4']) && isset($_POST['snippet5']) && isset($_POST['snippet6'])) {

  if(empty($_POST['age']) || empty($_POST['id']) || empty($_POST['image']) || empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['snippet0']) || empty($_POST['snippet1']) 
    || empty($_POST['snippet2']) || empty($_POST['snippet3']) || empty($_POST['snippet4']) || empty($_POST['snippet5']) || empty($_POST['snippet6'])) {
    echo 'All fields are required';
  }
  else {
    $postArray = array(
      "age" => $_POST['age'],
      "id" => $_POST['id'],
      "image" => $_POST['image'],
      "name" => $_POST['name'],
      "snippet0" => $_POST['snippet0'],
      "snippet1" => $_POST['snippet1'],
      "snippet2" => $_POST['snippet2'],
      "snippet3" => $_POST['snippet3'],
      "snippet4" => $_POST['snippet4'],
      "snippet5" => $_POST['snippet5'],
      "snippet6" => $_POST['snippet6']
    );


$jsondata = json_encode ( $postArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );


$file = 'data/formdata.json';
if(file_put_contents( $file, $jsondata, FILE_APPEND )) echo 'Data saved';
else echo 'Unable to save data';
  }
}
else echo 'Form fields not submitted';
?>
```

Here's an example of the JSON output I get with it:

```
{
    "age": "1",
    "id": "bob",
    "image": "bob.png",
    "name": "Bob.com",
    "snippet0": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet1": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet2": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet3": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet4": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet5": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet6": "sub.bob.com"
}{
    "age": "1",
    "id": "bob",
    "image": "bob.png",
    "name": "Bob.com",
    "snippet0": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet1": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet2": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet3": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet4": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet5": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet6": "sub.bob.com"
}
```

And finally, an example of the JSON output I want:

```
[{
    "age": "1",
    "id": "bob",
    "image": "bob.png",
    "name": "Bob.com",
    "snippet0": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet1": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet2": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet3": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet4": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet5": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet6": "sub.bob.com"
},{
    "age": "1",
    "id": "bob",
    "image": "bob.png",
    "name": "Bob.com",
    "snippet0": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet1": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet2": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet3": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet4": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet5": "sub.bob.com",
    "snippet6": "sub.bob.com"
}]
```

Comment: before file_put_contents get json from file, use `json_decode`, add new values, use `json_encode`, and run `file_put_contents` without FILE_APPEND

Comment: What values do I need to add for json_decode?

Comment: new data - $postArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read from the file

```
$file_content = json_decode( file_get_contents('data/formdata.json') );
```

Then add the data

```
$file_content []= 
    array(
      "age" => $_POST['age'],
      "id" => $_POST['id'],
      "image" => $_POST['image'],
      "name" => $_POST['name'],
      "snippet0" => $_POST['snippet0'],
      "snippet1" => $_POST['snippet1'],
      "snippet2" => $_POST['snippet2'],
      "snippet3" => $_POST['snippet3'],
      "snippet4" => $_POST['snippet4'],
      "snippet5" => $_POST['snippet5'],
      "snippet6" => $_POST['snippet6']
    );
```

In the end just put the content back into the file

```
$file_content = json_encode ( $file_content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
file_put_contents( 'data/formdata.json', $file_content );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, just make a option in second parameter in `json_encode` function

```
JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
```

Example:

```
json_encode($date,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```